# Retrieving a database record set into an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, dataset

I want to retrieve a set of records from a MySQL table as an array.

So far I was able to retrieve each row as an associative array. But I want all the rows in one array because I have to access that complete object in jQuery to display them.

This is what I have done so far.This is my .php script to retrieve data

```
//select query    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student",$con) or die (mysql_error());

$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result); //to iterate the for loop

//passing as an associative array

for ($count = 0; $count < $numRows; $count++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    echo json_encode($row);     
}
```

This is what I currently get

```
{"StuId":"1","fName":"Saman","lName":"Kumara","age":"14","grade":"A"}
{"StuId":"2","fName":"Marry","lName":"Vass","age":"12","grade":"B"}
{"StuId":"3","fName":"Navjoth","lName":"Bogal","age":"32","grade":"A"}
{"StuId":"4","fName":"Jassu","lName":"Singh","age":"22","grade":"E"}
```

But I want this result set as follows.

```
[
    {"TEST1":45,"TEST2":23,"TEST3":"DATA1"},
    {"TEST1":46,"TEST2":24,"TEST3":"DATA2"},
    {"TEST1":47,"TEST2":25,"TEST3":"DATA3"}
]
```

I seek help in doing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is No relation between your desired output and current output!!!!

Comment: `Associative array` always output as **object** `{}` but  you want it like **array** `[]`

Comment: Actually I wanted all the rows in one array.In the current output I'm getting separate arrays.As I want to run all the rows using a for loop the current output was not appropriate :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put it all in one array, then json_encode it:

```
$json = array( );
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM student",$con) or die (mysql_error());
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode( $json );
```

FYI: there's no need to count the number of results to loop. mysql_fetch_* will internally keep a pointer to the current record and increment that on each call. That makes it a perfect candidate to use in a simple while loop. Also, instead of mysql_fetch_array and passing MYSQL_ASSOC, you can simply use mysql_fetch_assoc instead, a method I much prefer. Makes the code easier to read too (in my opinion, anyway).

Comment: Hi Berry,
Thanks alot,It worked :)
I was bit struggling to do this 
Cheers...!!!!

Comment: Berry
I would like to know some other points.
when I'm going to display this data in an html page what method should I use?
can I access this data 
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url: 'beta.php' ,
data:"",
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data){
});

or should I use the getJSON(){}.If I'm using this method is there a specific way to retrieve the results?I mean like creating a separate file? 
And sorry about not accepting the answer.I'll do it right away :)

Comment: Hi. That is a different question, perhaps it's beneficiary for yourself and other to create a new question instead. That said, I'd use .getJSON, otherwise you'll have to eval( ) that yourself, I think.

Comment: Hi,I just notice the result of the output of the above code.I get the result as
[
Object { StuId="1", fName="Saman", more...}, 
Object { StuId="2", fName="Marry", more...}, 
Object { StuId="3", fName="Navjoth", more...}, 
Object { StuId="4", fName="Jassu", more...}
]
I think this might be the problem I'm unable to iterate through the array in jQuery.

Can u tell me why this is happening and what should I do to correct it.

Comment: @Yasoda that shouldn't happen and certainly wouldn't with the code I presented. I don't see why you wouldn't be able to traverse the array though?