# Multidimensional Array from SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here's the my SQL table:

```
order_id | product_id | deal_title | currency_code | total | date_modified
```

My Question is how do I make an array in PHP like in the below:

```
Array
(
    [product_id_num1] => Array
        (
            [order_id]
            [deal_title]
            [currency_code]
            [total]
            [date_modified]
        )
    [product_id_num2] => Array
        (
            [order_id]
            [deal_title]
            [currency_code]
            [total]
            [date_modified]
        )
    [product_id_num3] => Array
        (
            [order_id]
            [deal_title]
            [currency_code]
            [total]
            [date_modified]
        )
etc....
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to do it in brute force way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184694/retrieving-a-database-record-set-into-an-array-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like below

```
$arr = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {
    $id = $row['product_id'];
    unset($row['product_id']);
    $arr[$id] = $row;
}
```

Comment: @EatCodePlaySleep : Are you using `mysqli_*` or `mysql_*` functions? What is the error it shows? If no error is thrown use `print_r($arr)` after the while block to understand the structure of `$arr` array

Comment: nice! got it working now. just forgot one syntax. :)