# NodeJS Get Two Rows With Different Data

Tags: php, mysql, node.js

Im using NodeJS and I need to get any mysql rows with different data counted (Only numbers row):

```
numbers name

12345 | hello
12345 | hello
54151 | okay
```

I only need to get these lines: 
12345 | hello and 54151 | okay
So I should get: 2, because its 2 different lines.

What is function to do this?

Im currently using:

```
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(distinct numbers) FROM users as DistinctCount', function (err, row, fields) {
if (err) {
throw err;
} 
else {
console.log(row[0].DistinctCount);
}
});
```

But it logs: undefined.

Comment: What determines what name you display fro number 12345?  If you don't care you could just `select numbers, name from users group by numbers` and name will be a "random" selection when multiple values exist for a given number.  Note this works in mySQL because of the mySQL group by extensions, in other RDBMS you would have to use min or max or define a ruleset to determine which name to select.

Comment: Name is already set with the number, and I need to get only count of lines with different numbers

Comment: `select count(Distinct number) from users;`  This will return a count of the unique numbers in the users table.  Distinct forces the engine to get unique values of numbers from the users table, count is just that a count of those unique values.

Comment: Im using this now, but how can I show it in console?

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt work                                   console.log(row[0].count);

Comment: sorry should have aliased it `select count(Distinct number) as DistinctCount` and then from users; just display the 'DistinctCount' Column from the RecordSet.  Example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184694/retrieving-a-database-record-set-into-an-array-in-php or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366029/does-php-have-a-construct-similar-to-nets-dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
select count(Distinct number) as DistinctCount FROM users;
```